# installing Trac / Python / SetupTools on Windows (Server 2008 R2)

Tags: python, easy-install, trac

I am trying to install Trac on a Windows Server 2008 R2 server 64-bit.

I am following the guide on http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInstall.  I first installed Python, installing the `Python 2.7.2 Windows Installer`. (32-bit version).

Then, I tried to install `Setup Tools` using the guidelines here: http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#installing-setuptools.

It seemed to install successfully, however when I run `easy_install` i always get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\Scripts\easy_install-script.py", line 5, in <module>
      from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
```

Searching on google about the `pkg_resources` all pointed to an incorrectly installed `setuptools`, but I followed all the steps!

any ideas

Answer (score 0):

This is incredibly late (but better late than never I suppose!).

Take a look at the installer version: `Python 2.7.2` Then take a look at your traceback (+1 for posting that): The error is in `C:\Python26\..`

You want to either change your `PATH` environment variable to point to your Python 2.7 install path (presumably `C:\Python27\`), or use the Python 2.6 installer for setuptools.